# Code is getting infinitely stuck on the conn.recv(4) line of the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

The following is my echo server code:

```
# echo-server.py

import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

old_data = ""

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    print("Now listening")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            new_data = conn.recv(4)
            if not new_data:
                conn.sendall(old_data.encode())
                break
            old_data += new_data.decode()
```

And the following is my client code:

```
import socket

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 65432

print("Will try to send")

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break

print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

Just like i said in the title the code gets stuck on the 18th line of the server after a few iterations after it has received the entire message. And i dont know how to make it work.

I was trying to recieve data 4 bytes at a time on my server so i set the buffer to 4 bytes and set up a while loop to recieve the hello world 4 bytes at a time and then send the whole message back. However the code gets stuck on the 18th line of the server after a few iterations after it has received the entire message. How do i get it to work?

Comment: It `break`s the loop after first `conn.send_all` and stops the server. Is it desired to be like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is assuming that `conn.recv(4)` will return if the peer has just stopped sending data. This assumption is wrong. `conn.recv(4)` will only return if the peer has closed the socket or at least shutdown for writing. Only this **explicitly** notifies the peer that no more data will be send ever on this connection. Everything else will just be treated as a temporary pause (of unknown duration) in sending and `recv` will wait for more data or the final close/shutdown.